# NSTimer displayed in label then disappears?

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a viewController that loads my imagePickerController from a button action. When the imagePickerController loads it should display, with an overlay, two labels with predetermined data. One is timerLabel and the other is titleLabel. Both labels are displayed with the correct data when the imagePickerController first loads but after only a moment, the timerLabel data disappears but the label itself is still there. In my refreshLabel method, the NSLogged timerLabel is correct but when it gets to the NSLog for startDate and timeLeft it returns (null). Any ideas? thanks!

```
    - (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {
        if (self.image == nil &&  [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
            self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
            self.imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            }
            else {
                self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            }
            self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePickerController.sourceType];
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];}

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(160,8,0,0);
        self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt",
                              documentsDirectory];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/name.txt",
                               documentsDirectory];
        NSError *fileError;
        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:name
                                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                       error:&fileError];
        timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:deadline
                                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                       error:&fileError];
        if(fileError.code == 0){
            NSLog(@"deadline.txt was read successfully with these contents: %@,",
                  timerLabel.text);
            NSLog(@"name.txt was read successfully with these contents: %@,",
                  titleLabel.text);}


     NSLog(@"timer label %@", timerLabel.text);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(refreshLabel)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void)refreshLabel {
    NSLog(@"timer label %@", timerLabel.text);

    NSDate *startDate = [self.formatter dateFromString:timerLabel.text];
    NSDate *timeLeft = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];

    NSLog(@"start time %@",startDate);
    NSLog(@"time left %@",timeLeft);

    NSTimeInterval totalCountdownInterval =1;
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [timeLeft timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimeInterval remainingTime = totalCountdownInterval - elapsedTime;

    self.timerLabel.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:timeLeft];

    if (remainingTime <= 0.0) {
        //dismiss controller and set to homecontroller at tabBar index 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that it's the label itself that goes away, or just the text in the label? If you don't know, give the label a background color, and then you'll be able to see.

Comment: Good call. It is just the text in the label. The background color sticks around. Do you know what it could be? It's got to be something with the refreshLabel method that isn't syncing up.

Comment: You should do some logging to track down the problem. Log startDate and timeLeft to make sure neither is nil. Also, you should move the first two lines in refreshLabel to somewhere else, like viewDidLoad -- no need to create a new one every time the timer fires.

Comment: hmm.. both are coming back as (null).

Comment: Then you need to back up one more, and log timerLabel.text in the startCamera: method.

Comment: Yes, the timer label is being logged correctly. In the NSLog it reads correctly and when the viewController is first loaded it appears on the screen correctly but is gone within a moments time.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I am trying to make a timer that counts down by 1 second increments from the startDate. I know the integers are not correct, I plan on adjusting them once I get the timer to display.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. I don't get why it's not reading startDate from timerLabel

Comment: why is there a semicolon in the refreshLabel method name?

Comment: just a type-o. I took it out and am still having the same problems :(

Comment: @rdelmar any ideas on where I can go to help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: What does the log of timerLabel.text in the startCamera: show. Does it match the format you set for your formatter? Those have to match, or the dateFromString: method will return null.

Comment: Yes, all the formats match. I rechecked the timerLabels NSLog at the beginning of refreshLabel method right before I assign startDate and timeLeft and it logs correctly as the previously chosen time formatted for dd:hh:mm:ss. But then it disappears from screen and the two dates (startDate & timeLeft) both return (null).

Comment: when I change my NSDate *startDate to equal [NSDate date] the timerLabel displays everything correctly and the Log shows the correct formatting for todays date and the timer works. But when I plug in my timerLabel.text in for startDate, it just disappears

Comment: Please show what timerLabel.text logs.

Comment: 2013-09-09 21:51:46.530 myApp[1674:907] timer label at beginning of refresh 0:23:59:56

Comment: So it's logging hh:mm:ss, but you said your format was dd:hh:mm:ss. Is that what you have, because those two do not match.

Comment: and right after that, the startDate logs Null and timeLeft logs Null. I assume that once the startDate gets set right that the timeLeft will follow suit. But the timerLabel on displays the right info on the first refresh. Every refresh after that, it returns null as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37078/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jared-gross)

Comment: It logs the days also.. I just hadn't set the timer for days that time. When I manually set it to be more than a day in the future it reads as  2:23:59:56